# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.WinForms'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can i solve this problem? I googled the title on google but results were 'CefSharp.dll', 'CefSharp.Core.dll', 'CefSharp.WinForms.dll' etc. There were no results about my issue. It says system can't find 'CefSharp.WinForms' (Which i added with NuGet) not the .dll's like 'CefSharp.dll, CefSharp.Core.dll or CefSharp.WinForms.dll'.

My Code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
namespace TurkishLeft
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
    public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.reddit.com/r/TurkishLeft/");
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeChromium();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example

Comment: @Tommy how do i use it?

Comment: First, download the project from GitHub, open in Visual Studio, compile and then run.  See if it works.  If it does, then walk through the example code on how they are setting it up and mirror your own code to behave like that.  I'm not a huge WinForms programmer, so some of the sample code doesn't make as much sense to me as it would if you were doing ASP.NET (web).  But anyways, this should serve as a working example project in which you can use the steps, function calls, order of setup, etc to get it working in your own project.  Good luck!